# Update environment variables of provisioned Container Instance

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

Has anyone ever tried to update the existing environment variable values after the container instance is provisioned in azure using Azure ACI?

Currently, it seems that there is no way to update them either using portal or using Azure CLI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in the following GitHub issue:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31168

In that issue, we point to the following document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update

All in all, you can update the variables however it still means recreating the container or "Redeploying" it with the update variables which in turns terminates the container and deploys a new one. So a bit of a yes and no answer and scenario.